# About isometry in $l_ \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, isometry

Let $1 \leq p<\infty$.

> Find an isometry $j: l_{\infty} \rightarrow L\left(L_{p}[0,1]\right)$ .

(Hint :first embed $ℓ_∞$ into $L^∞[0,1]$ and let this act on $L^p[0,1]$ as multiplication operators.)

I can't use Hint for solve this problem but I think  we can Use that fact that for $p>1$ the Haar basis $(h_n)$ of $L_p$ is 1-unconditional.

Comment: What is $L(L_p)$?

Comment: @copper.hat . If $X $ and $Y$ are normed spaces over the same ground field K, the set of all continuous K-linear maps $T : X → Y $ is denoted by $L(X, Y)$. If $X$ is a Banach space, the space $L(X) = L(X, X)$

Comment: Why don't you use the hint?

Comment: @copper.hat .  I can't embed $ℓ_∞$ into $L^∞[0,1]$  .

Comment: Why don't you look at my answer. There is an implicit embedding there.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

Let $t_k$ be a strictly increasing sequence such that $t_k \to 1$ and
let $I_k= [t_{k-1},t_k)$.

Suppose $x \in l_\infty$ and $f \in L^p[0,1]$.

Define $((j(x)(f))(t) = \sum_k x_k f(t) 1_{I_k}(t)$.

Then $\|j(x)\| = \|x\|$.

Comment: Why $\|j(x)\| = \|x\|$ ?

Comment: Did you try to compute the norm?

Comment: I can show $ \|j(x)\| \le  \|x\|$.

Comment: Compute $\| (j(x)) 1_{I_n} \|$. You need to try things.